# Проверка пустая строка или нет при помощи LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Пытаюсь записать это код при помощи LINQ

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in substrings)
{
    if (s != "")
    {
        list.Add(s.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Вот только незнаю, как написать условие if и чтобы итератор s входил в substrings.

```
list.ToList().ForEach(s => list.Add(s.ToLower()))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
substrings.Where(s => s != string.Empty)
          .Select(s => s.ToLower())
          .ToList()
```

Comment: Только предпочтительней string.IsNullOrEmpty вместо неравенства.

Comment: @STDray В варианте, где используется `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, код перестает быть эквивалентным коду топикстартера.

Answer (score 0):

Вот два варианта:

```
substrings.ToList().ForEach(s => { if (s != String.Empty)list.Add(s.ToLower()); });
  substrings.ToList().Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToList().ForEach(s => list.Add(s.ToLower()));
```

Но ваш лучше. Не делайте код сложным если в этом нет нужды, старайтесь писать как можно проще. Не нужно использовать LINQ лишь только потому, что он есть. Используйте когда реально нужно.

Comment: ok, спасибо за совет. Посмотрев на это лучше все таки оставить старый вариант, т.к. читабельность намного хуже становится.

Comment: Я бы ещё посоветовал использовать LINQ только если вы его понимаете. В частности, если вы понимаете, почему использование `ForEach` — [плохо](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).